# How to use browser's default loader?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

Currently, I am working on creating my blog. And there, I uses ajax infinite loader script. While loading posts it shows loading gif like this:

[image]

But I don't want to use that gif. Instead of that I want to use the browsers default loading bar(You must see these loading bar in the address bar while your requested page is loading in your browser. I attached that loader to help you).

[image: Loader screenshot]

Edit 1: Here is the link to script (https://helplogger.blogspot.com/2016/09/load-more-blogger-posts-or-infinite-scrolling.html) which I am using. You can easily find the gif link in the script. And I want that gif to replace with the built-in chrome/any browser loader.(Because I am thinking that this will decrease the blog time a little bit.)

Comment: Don't use AJAX and the browser will handle the loading state for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, Why "Don't use AJAX" ? I am beginner in web development. Your answers help me a lot.

Comment: If you want the browser do handle the loading state, the easiest way is to not use AJAX, and the browser can load the next page for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can make one like that without use of image. You will need css and html.

## HTML

```
<div class="loader">
  <svg class="circular" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
   <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.loader {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100px;
}

.loader:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.circular {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
  animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center center;
  transform-origin: center center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1, 200;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  -webkit-animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite, color 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite, color 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

@-webkit-keyframes 
rotate {  100% {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
 transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}

@keyframes 
rotate {  100% {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
 transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes 
  dash {  0% {
 stroke-dasharray: 1, 200;
 stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
 50% {
 stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
 stroke-dashoffset: -35;
}
 100% {
 stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
 stroke-dashoffset: -124;
}
}

@keyframes 
dash {  0% {
 stroke-dasharray: 1, 200;
 stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
 50% {
 stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
 stroke-dashoffset: -35;
}
 100% {
 stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
 stroke-dashoffset: -124;
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes 
color {  100%, 0% {
 stroke: #3cba54;
}
 40% {
 stroke: #3cba54;
}
 66% {
 stroke: #3cba54;
}
 80%, 90% {
 stroke: #3cba54;
}
}
```

See Live [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jw4yrvgb/)
You should change colors according to your theme
Try it...

Source: https://www.cssscript.com/animated-google-loader-with-svg-and-css/

Comment: I don't think he wants the loading indicator in the page at all, he wants it to use the browser's built-in chrome.